# Javascript Class returns private variable and not getter

Tags: javascript

I would expect an instance of the following class to return both the "private" variable AND it's getter, but the getter variable is not returned at all.  Why?

```
class Foo {
  _myPrivateVar = null;

  get myPublicVar() {
    return this._myPrivateVar;
  }

  set myPublicVar(v) {
    if (v > 4) {
      this._myPrivateVar = v;
    }
  }
}

const f = new Foo();
console.log(f) // Foo { _myPrivateVar: 5 }
```

I expected `{ _myPrivateVar: 5, myPublicVar: 5 }`.  I understand I can access `f.myPublicVar` directly, but the problem is when return the instance from an Express server, for example, the resulting JSON object is devoid of the getter property `myPublicVar`.  Why?

Comment: The getter/setter are on the prototype, not the instance (and have enumerable: false).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The getter and setter is on the *prototype*, whereas `_myPrivateVar` is put on the instance itself.

When an object is serialized with `JSON.stringify`, such as for transfer over the network, only enumerable own properties will be included in the resulting JSON:

```js
const obj = Object.create({ foo: 'foo' });
obj.bar = 'bar';
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Another issue is that class instances usually can't be meaningfully stringified - when parsed on the other side, they'll be interpreted as *plain* objects, arrays, and values.

If you want to do something like this, you'll have to come up with a way to serialize the instance such that it can be turned into a proper instance on the other side. For a very basic example, if you put all instances into a `foos` array when sending, you can create a new object with an internal prototype of`Foo.prototype` on the other side for every item in the array:

```js
// Sending
class Foo {
  _myPrivateVar = null;

  get myPublicVar() {
    return this._myPrivateVar;
  }

  set myPublicVar(v) {
    if (v > 4) {
      this._myPrivateVar = v;
    }
  }
}

const f1 = new Foo();
f1.myPublicVar = 5;
const f2 = new Foo();
f2.myPublicVar = 1;

console.log(JSON.stringify({ foos: [f1, f2] }));
```

```js
// Receiving
class Foo {
  _myPrivateVar = null;

  get myPublicVar() {
    return this._myPrivateVar;
  }

  set myPublicVar(v) {
    if (v > 4) {
      this._myPrivateVar = v;
    }
  }
}

const json = `{"foos":[{"_myPrivateVar":5},{"_myPrivateVar":null}]}`;
const { foos } = JSON.parse(json);

const properFoos = foos.map(({ _myPrivateVar }) => {
  const foo = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
  foo._myPrivateVar = _myPrivateVar;
  return foo;
});
console.log(properFoos[0].myPublicVar);
console.log(properFoos[1].myPublicVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript.info](https://javascript.info/class#class-properties)

> The property name is not placed into User.prototype. Instead, it is created by new before calling the constructor, it’s a property of the object itself.

```js
class User {
  name = "Anonymous";

  sayHi() {
    console.log(`Hello, ${this.name}!`);
  }
}

new User().sayHi();

console.log('sayHi:',User.prototype.sayHi); // placed in User.prototype
console.log('name:',User.prototype.name); // undefined, not placed in User.prototype
```